# ffmpeg libx264 is noisy

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, transcode

After converting video with `ffmpeg` to H264, my video is noisy.

```
ffmpeg -i http://192.168.1.10:5530/bysid/106 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -c:v libx264 -c:a mp2 out.mkv
```

Normal:
[image: Normal]

Noisy subtitle:
[image: Noisy subtitle]

Same result with tag preset ultrafast, slow.
Same result with GPU transcode.

Comment: Add deinterlacing and check: `-vf yadif`

Comment: thank you. its very better now! but not perfect

Comment: Yeah, the scroll is horizontal so deinterlacing won't completely mask that.

Comment: Can I use a codec that does not cause this problem?

Comment: You can encode as interlaced. Add `-flags +ilme+ildct` but not `-vf yadif`.